# .NET-PowerShell Write-Error stream event handler is not called

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm calling this [PS module](https://github.com/Microsoft/StoreBroker) from C# code. I add `EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs>` to `powershellInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded` but it is never called and `powershellInstance.Streams.Error.Count` after execution is always 0. The reason I know there should be error is I execute the same command manually and I can see error print out.

Looking at the [logging function](https://github.com/Microsoft/StoreBroker/blob/master/StoreBroker/Helpers.ps1) of the module, they use `Write-Error` so I don't see why I can't capture this, I can capture `Write-Warning`, `-Debug`, `-Progress`, and `-Verbose` just fine.

Any suggestion?

Below is my PowerShell C# code:

```
    private System.Management.Automation.PowerShell powershellInstance = null;

    public async Task<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> Execute(
        string script,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        ExecutionPolicy executionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Default,
        IList listParams = null,
        IDictionary pairParams = null,
        EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs> verboseHandler = null,
        EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs> debugHandler = null,
        EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs> warningHandler = null,
        EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs> errorHandler = null,
        EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs> progressHandler = null)
    {
        powershellInstance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
        LastOutputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
        powershellInstance.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
        powershellInstance.AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", executionPolicy.ToString());
        powershellInstance.AddParameter("Force");
        powershellInstance.AddScript(script);
        if (listParams != null && listParams.Count > 0)
        {
            powershellInstance.AddParameters(listParams);
        }

        if (pairParams != null && pairParams.Count > 0)
        {
            powershellInstance.AddParameters(pairParams);
        }

        if (verboseHandler != null)
        {
            powershellInstance.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += verboseHandler;
        }

        if (debugHandler != null)
        {
            powershellInstance.Streams.Debug.DataAdded += debugHandler;
        }

        if (warningHandler != null)
        {
            powershellInstance.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += warningHandler;
        }

        if (errorHandler != null)
        {
            powershellInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded += errorHandler;
        }

        if (progressHandler != null)
        {
            powershellInstance.Streams.Progress.DataAdded += progressHandler;
        }
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            PSDataCollection<PSObject> result = null;
            var actionResult = powershellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(
                null /* input */,
                LastOutputCollection);
            WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { actionResult.AsyncWaitHandle, cancellationToken.WaitHandle });
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                powershellInstance.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                InvokeCallback(actionResult);
                result = powershellInstance.EndInvoke(actionResult);
            }
            powershellInstance.Dispose();
            return result;
        });
    }

    public void InvokeCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Info("Powershell callback invoked. AsyncResult completed = {5}. {0} errors. {1} warnings. {2} debugs. {3} progress. {4} verbose.",
                powershellInstance.Streams.Error.Count,
                powershellInstance.Streams.Warning.Count,
                powershellInstance.Streams.Debug.Count,
                powershellInstance.Streams.Progress.Count,
                powershellInstance.Streams.Verbose.Count,
                asyncResult.IsCompleted
                );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.FatalException("Exception in InvokeCallback", ex);
        }
    }
```

And here is my error handler:

```
    public void PSErrorHandler(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs arg)
    {
        log.Info($"PSErrorHandler called. Sender type is {sender.GetType()}");
        PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord> records = sender as PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>;
        ErrorRecord record = records[arg.Index];
        LogError($"PSError: ErrorId: {record.FullyQualifiedErrorId}. Message: {record.ErrorDetails.Message}; Recommendation: {record.ErrorDetails.RecommendedAction}.").Wait();
        LogError($"PSError-Exception: Message: {record.Exception.Message}; Source: {record.Exception.Source}; Trace: {record.Exception.StackTrace}.").Wait();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you see printed out when you run the PowerShell manually?  Also, do you have error handling built-into the PS script in any way?  Can you provide that script, or is it too lengthy/proprietary?

Comment: How are you actually using the `Execute` method?

Comment: Can you construct [mcve]?